# How to print all magento configurations (config array) : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

We can get individual configuration of magento 2 using:

`echo $this->getConfig('xxxx/xxxx');`

But is there any way where we can print/show all the configurations which exists in configuration array for magento 2

I have tried as `print_r($this->getConfig());` but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code I have not try by my own but this need to work

In your block class

```
protected $config;   
public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value $config,
    .....
) {
    $this->config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
public function YourFunction(){
   return  $this->config->getCollection(); //this will return object you can get data using $this->config->getCollection()->getData();
}
```